# Changing matplotlib's dashed line characteristics other than just line width

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plot generated from matplotlib:

[image: matplotlib spiral]

I've found out how to change the *width* of the line, but I would like to change the *length* of the individual segments. I can't find where this is in the matplotlib documentation. How do I do this?

Also, while I'm here, is there a way to change the spacing between the segments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dashes=[...]` to specify a [custom dash pattern](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/dash_control.html). For example, `dashes=[5, 3]` tells `plt.plot` to draw 5 points "on" followed by 3 points "off".

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.linspace(0, 9*np.pi, 100)
r = theta
x = r * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.sin(theta)
plt.plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=5, dashes=[5, 3])
plt.show()
```

[image]